# rsync within a perl script having permission errors

Tags: macos, rsync, perl

I have a share on one mac that I am trying to rsync a set of directories from a second mac.

The share is mounted on the second mac and `ls -l` shows access like for all the directories `drwx---rwx  1 shaun  staff  466 Nov 23 06:53 Backup`, but I am getting the error: `rsync: failed to set times on "/Volumes/Data/Media Library/Documents": Permission denied (13)`.

The perl script (with only one test directory) is:

```
$source = '/Volumes/LEXAR64GB';
$destination = '/Volumes/Data/Media Library';
@folders = ('Documents');
print "Working…\n";
foreach $i (@folders) {
    print "Processing: $i\n";
    system("rsync -arub --delete --backup-dir='$destination/rsync backup' --modify-window=1 '$source/$i/' '$destination/$i'");
}
```

Should I be running the command as a different user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, that Mac OS uses NFS to share over network.

This is from rsync man page, give it a try.

> -O, --omit-dir-times
>       This tells rsync to omit directories when it is preserving modification times (see --times). **If NFS is sharing the directories
>   on the receiving side, it is a good idea to use -O**. This option is
>   inferred if you use --backup without --backup-dir.

Comment: +1 for O, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/667992/1081936) on SO could also interest you @shaun5.

Comment: Mac OS X doesn't use NFS, but it may work